# QT QDebug with QIODevice not working

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I wanted my QT application to store certain logs in different files.
I had been using `qDebug() << "LOG Messages"` to output information.
The problem in this method is that all output will come on the same screen even if you are threading.
The QDebug class documents that I can make a QDebug(QIODevice * dev) to give any QIODEvice as the device to store data. So I wrote the following code but it doesnt work :

```
QString logfilePath = "/var/log/1.log";
QFile * logfile = new QFile(logfilePath);
if(!logfile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append)){
    // There is an error
}else{
    QDebug * logger = new QDebug(logfile);
    *logger << "msg";
}
```

The file is created but no information is stored in the file.
I even checked the QDebug code and it looks like it creates a TEXT Stream on the QIODevice.
So why is no output being stored in the file ?

Also I know the qMessageInstaller function. But it wont work for me because it is a universal handler and I would like different threads to store log messages in different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
*logger << "Hello!" << endl;
```

Or this

```
*logger << "Hello!" << flush;
```

Remember to delete logger, which will flush the stream too.

```
delete logger;
```

Make sure you are writing to different files in different threads too.

Comment: Is there no way to flush it as the test stream is given text ?

Comment: @user1066991, yes, please see the mutated answer.

Comment: Note: This is not `std::endl`, but `endl` from `QTextStream` (I learned the hard way)